# Mi banner solo funciona una vez

Tags: android-studio, admob

Tengo una app con varios banners que algunos utilizan el mismo banner id(el que da admob)  el problema es que solo se muestra una vez después entro a otra activity y al volver nunca vuelve a poner el banner, es el caso para toda mi app.
Este es mi código:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "id_de_app"); 
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView); 
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

En la cuestión gráfica y la declaración en manifest es tal cual me indica que lo haga el sitio de android developer.
A alguien le ha sucedido lo mismo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No importa si usas el mismo id del anuncio, en este caso debes tomar en cuenta que la carga de un anuncio, **de forma predeterminada la carga del anuncio puede tardar hasta 30 segundos**.

La carga puede depender también de la conexión y puede ser mayor si el anuncio es [**interstitial**](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201350?hl=es).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debes revisar también si el contenedor donde cargas el anuncio cambio de tamaño, recuerda que según el tipo de anuncio este se puede desplegar ùnicamente en la medida de contenedor definida.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de otra forma en el LogCat podrás ver un error

> Not enough space to show ad. Needs ..x.. dp, but only has ..x.. dp.

y el anuncio no se mostraría.

Puedo sugerirte implementar un [AdListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener?hl=es) a tu anuncio, en el método `onAdFailedToLoad()` podrías encontrar si en realidad se tiene algún tipo de problema en la carga del mismo.

```
mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdOpened() {
        // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
        // covers the screen.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClicked() {
        // Code to be executed when the user clicks on an ad.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLeftApplication() {
        // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        // Code to be executed when the user is about to return
        // to the app after tapping on an ad.
    }
});
```